# Assign/Create controller while creating Ember View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ember.js

```
var view = Ember.View.extend({

 templateName: 'some',
//action: 'save',
//click: function () { this.triggerAction(); },
init: function () {
 this._super();
this.set('controller', App.SomeController.create())
 }

});
view.create().appendTo("#divMain");
```

Here i am creating the view and appending to a div, however here i have to explicity set the controller  `this.set('controller', App.SomeController.create())`

Is it possible to implicitly assign the controller while creating view?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's kind of going backwards.

View's don't "have" a controller.  Controller's "manage" a view.  And the majority of time the parent controller is managing the view.  Think of all of the reusable items, input helper, link-to etc, all views, backed by their parent controller.

That being said when you visit a route Ember hooks up the template to the view/controller backing that route.  Often these are default implementations and you haven't specified anything different.

Here's the controller property on the Ember View.

```
  /**
    The controller managing this view. If this property is set, it will be
    made available for use by the template.

    @property controller
    @type Object
  */
  controller: Ember.computed(function(key) {
    var parentView = get(this, '_parentView');
    return parentView ? get(parentView, 'controller') : null;
  }).property('_parentView'),
```

Comment: However the problem is that the templateName is being fetched from the server and view is rendered dynamically. So is it that on the route itself i should create the view and append to DOM

Comment: Can you go into more detail about the problem?  Like why you need a controller etc.

Comment: :I am trying to dynamically load the view from server. however when i am creating the view, it is not getting the controller hence the events are not getting wired.